# Why is my window.outerWidth greater than my window.innerWidth even though I have no elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Trying to tick off all of the PWA requirements for my React web app and I cannot seem to figure out the "Content is sized correctly for the viewport" requirement.

For some reason, the window.outerWidth of my site is greater than the window.innerWidth, even after I have removed every element from the page!

Couple of things I have double checked:

- Have set the html <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width"
- Have zoom set to 100%
- Have ensured the dev tools panel is docked 'below' rather than to the side

The HTML of the page - no elements:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdSgi.png

The page itself - nothing there!:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzS0d.png

The difference in window widths from a console.log on render:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3UE3.png

Would appreciate any help!

Full html below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="xxxx."
    />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="critical.css"></link>
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <link
    as="script"
    rel="preconnect"
    href="https://storage.googleapis.com"
    async>
    </link>
    <link 
      as="script" rel="preconnect"
      href="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xx"
      async
    ></link>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
      }
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'xx');
    </script>
    <link 
    as="script"
      data-ad-client="xx"
      rel="preconnect"
      href="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"
      async
    ></script>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/appleIcon.png" rel="preload"></link>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your padding/ margin/ border.

Comment: @NickHolden - thanks Nick, padding/margin/border on what? I've removed all elements and the html and body also have no rules in my css file

Comment: Can you please share your full HTML?

Comment: Added - thanks for having a look

Comment: Thanks!
It looks fine, and I'm also getting the same inner/outer width on my end.
Your screenshot has some scripts running in the body. If you run the code you attached (without the scripts), are you still getting the same result, with a different inner/outer width?
Also, I don't have critical.css, and that may change the behavior of your page. If you can share that as well, that might hold the solution.

Comment: Yeah this is the weird thing - if I remove all the scripts and even the css file (critical.css), I still get the same issue.

Comment: I think your window is not expanded to fill your screen all the way through, which is why innerWidth is just a bit smaller. Can you please verify this?

Comment: Not quite sure how to verify that - I have the following rule in critical.css:

html, body {
width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      border: 0;
      overflow: hidden; /*  Disable scrollbars */
      display: block;
}

Comment: I meant the actual browser window. Try maximizing the browser.

Comment: So yes if I maximise it they do match but at any other window size they are not the same - is that normal? I still fail the lighthouse test when maximised, I guess it can see that at different resolutions they won't match

Comment: I'm not sure tbh, but my best guess would be zoom, which would make that difference. try reverting the browser size to what it was, and make sure the browsers zoom is set to 100% (windows: ctrl+0 or mac: cmd+0)